# Qgis: Labels don't show up after closing and reopening map

Tags: plugins, label, gis, qgis

I am using the Easy Custom Labelling 1.3.3 in QGIS 2.8.4 on Mac.

I created a label layer for a specific layer, and did some work on it while in edit mode. Then saved the edits, saved the label layer, and closed the map.

Now I open the map again, and none of the labels is there. And I can't get them back. I don't know if it is linked, but the edit boxes are red in the text section of the labelling for this label layer. [image: Screen shot]

I am stuck, and couldn't find such a problem here or on the web. Thank you!

Comment: Being in/out the editing mode doesn't help

Comment: You might have better luck on https://gis.stackexchange.com for questions on how to use GIS.